# Send automatic email from excel to outlook

Tags: excel

Just a question is that possible to send email alert from excel to outlook without need to use macros. What I mean is create a sheet in excel that contain name, email, email body, email subject, due date, remainder time. When it almost to due date, student will get the email without lecturer need to click on button send email or hyperlink send email in cell. For example, they set the due date on 24 February 2023, thus on that day student will automatic get email which is lectures don't have to open excel and click on the button

I already made it before where lecturer need to click button in excel to send email to student but they don't want in that way.

I just wanna know if we can use VBA to send automatic email without use macros or hyperlink. If cannot then I'll follow up with them

Comment: Using VBA = macros. However, you can run code in events that are triggered by opening the workbook for example. That's without the need to push a button and can even be automated to run at startup. Then the only thing you need to do is letting the macro check the dates and send the mail(s). This would require for Excel to be opened by a scheduled automation or by the lecturer (which honestly isn't that big of an ask imho).

Comment: Check this site https://officetricks.com/excel-vba-send-email-at-specific-time-delay-delivery/   first result from google  https://www.google.com/search?q=outlook+schedule+email+vba   , this is new technology googling (:  try it before asking.